# Prompt not displaying as expected in conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a console application in Node.js. The application traverses a series of pages. If on three consecutive pages no new posts are found, a prompt should display allowing the user to stop searching for new posts.

```
            // If the last three main pages haven't found any new posts, prompt the user to stop scraping
            if (numNewPostsFound == 0) {
                numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts++;
            } else {
                numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts = 0; 
            }

            if (numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts > 2) {
                let userChoice = prompt("No new posts have been found lately. Enter 'Y' to stop searching:");
                if (userChoice === 'Y') {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Full code below:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const reader = require('@mozilla/readability');
const axios = require("axios");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });



// URL of blog homepage
const baseURL = 'target_blog_homepage_url';

// Local file to contain JSON data describing posts
const filePath = 'backup.json';

// Array to hold JSON objects corresponding to posts 
let backup = [];

let totalPostsAdded = 0;

// Program entry point
crawl();

async function crawl() {
    try {

        // Read backup.json into memory if it exists 
        loadOrCreateFile()

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const mainPage = await browser.newPage();
        await mainPage.goto(baseURL, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            timeout: 30000
        });
        let numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts = 0;
        let { nextPage, numNewPostsFound } = await scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts(mainPage);
        let numTimesOlderPostsClicked = 1;


        while (nextPage) {
            console.log(`Older posts has been clicked ${numTimesOlderPostsClicked} times`)
            await mainPage.goto(nextPage, {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
                timeout: 30000
            });

            ({ nextPage, numNewPostsFound } = await scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts(mainPage));
            numTimesOlderPostsClicked++;

            // If the last three main pages haven't found any new posts, prompt the user to stop scraping
            if (numNewPostsFound == 0) {
                numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts++;
            } else {
                numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts = 0; 
            }

            if (numMainPagesWithNoNewPosts > 2) {
                let userChoice = prompt("No new posts have been found lately. Enter 'Y' to stop searching:");
                if (userChoice === 'Y') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("Releasing browser resources...");
        await mainPage.close();
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Browser resources have been released");

        // Sort array of posts by id (date)
        backup.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);

        // Write backup to file 
        writeFile(backup);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts(mainPage) {
    try {

        let postsAddedFromMainPage = 0;

        // Find links matching a post href
        const hrefs = await mainPage.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));
        const regex = /^https:\/\/target_blog_homepage_url\.blogspot\.com\/\d+\/.*\.html$/; // TODO update target_blog_homepage_url
        const filteredHrefs = hrefs.filter(url => regex.test(url));


        // For each href corresponding to a post, visit and scrape
        const postPromises = filteredHrefs.map(async (post) => {
            const resp = await axios.get(post);
            const html = resp.data;
            const dom = new JSDOM(html);
            const document = dom.window.document;

            // Use Readability to access post title and content
            const article = new reader.Readability(document).parse();

            // Create JSON object describing a post
            let postData = new Object();
            const postIdPattern = /\((\d+)\)$/;
            const matches = article.title.match(postIdPattern);

            postData.id = matches ? matches[1] : null;
            postData.title = article.title;
            postData.content = article.textContent;
            postData.URL = post;

            /* If object is not a duplicate, append it to the backup
            Here title has been used instead of id as not all posts will have an id */
            const titleExists = backup.some(item => item.title === postData.title);
            if (!titleExists) {
                backup.push(postData);
                postsAddedFromMainPage++;
                totalPostsAdded++;
            }
        });

        await Promise.all(postPromises);
        console.log(`Found ${postsAddedFromMainPage} new posts to baclup`);

        // If the main page has an href to older posts, return this href
        const nextPage = await mainPage.evaluate(() => {
            const idToFind = "Blog1_blog-pager-older-link";
            const anchorElement = document.getElementById(idToFind);

            if (anchorElement) {
                return anchorElement.getAttribute("href");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });

        return { nextPage, postsAddedFromMainPage };

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }
}

// If a backup file already exists, load it into memory 
function loadOrCreateFile() {
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        try {
            console.log("Backup file exists. Reading it into memory...")
            const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
            backup = JSON.parse(jsonData);
            console.log("Backup file loaded.")
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error reading or parsing existing JSON backup file:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error(`Backup JSON file does not exist, it will be created as ${filePath}`);
    }
}

// Write backup array of post objects to file
function writeFile(data) {
    console.log("Writing JSON data to backup file...");
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, jsonData);
    console.log(`JSON data has been written to ${filePath}`);
    console.log(`Added ${totalPostsAdded} posts to backup.`);
}
```

Program output demonstrates that the prompt is not displayed:

```
Found 5 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 1 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 2 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 3 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 4 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 5 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 6 times
Found 0 new posts to backup
Older posts has been clicked 7 times
```

Comment: Are you expecting a user to response to a prompt on your server-side code ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `destructuring` the wrong variable.

`numNewPostsFound` property is not returned from `scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts` function it actually returns like

```
{ nextPage, postsAddedFromMainPage } //object
```

Either destructure like this

```
let { nextPage, postsAddedFromMainPage:numNewPostsFound } = await scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts(mainPage)
```

or change the key in return statement of `scrapeCurrentlyShownPosts` function

```
{ nextPage, numNewPostsFound:postsAddedFromMainPage }
```